# For loop inside useEffect (unobvious behaviour)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, for-loop, react-hooks

I have a very simple React app to better understand how `useEffect` works.
This app has the App component with `useEffect` hook. Inside this hook, I simulate a heavy synchronous task using a `for` loop.
I am curious about the reasons behind the differing rendering outcomes when I place the `for` loop inside or outside the `if` condition.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    for (let index = 0; index < 1e9; index++) {}
    if (value === 0) {
      // or inside
      // for (let index = 0; index < 1e9; index++) {}
      setValue(Math.random());
    }
  }, [value]);

  return (
    <div>
      value: {value}
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => setValue(0)}>UseEffect</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is my code: https://codesandbox.io/s/useeffect-3zkw27

When I place `for` loop **outside** `if` condition:

[image]

When I place `for` loop **inside** `if` condition:

[image]

You can see that rendered value changes much faster when the loop is inside `if` condition. Any ideas why?

**UPDATE.** Ok, I have decided to change my code a bit in order to run `for` loop only once. Let's say I have `for` loop either inside `if` or inside `else`. Again, I have visually different behaviour... So I am closer to understand the behaviour, but still it is not clear.

```
useEffect(() => {
if (value === 0) {
  // for (let index = 0; index < 1e9; index++) {}
  setValue(Math.random());
} else {
  for (let index = 0; index < 1e9; index++) {}
}
```

}, [value]);

Comment: If it's inside the `if`, you only do the loop once per click (the render where it's equal to 0). If it's outside, you do it twice per click (the 0 render, and also the random number render).

Comment: @NicholasTower it doesnt matter, either way will cause component rerender twice. Once at onClick, once at inside useEffect.

Comment: The main problem is looping for `1e9` times is somewhat computationally intensive when you want the result to show up in an instance. Why did you want to loop for `1,00,000,000` times to learn how to use `useEffect` properly?

Comment: @NicholasTower Thank you, I see. But I thought that the second loop shouldn't have that much of an impact since useEffect is asynchronous and there is no rerender after the second loop (if for loop is outside)
I mean that the whole chain: click button -> setState(0) -> browser paints new value -> UseEffect (for loop, setState(random)) -> browser paints new value -> UseEffect (w for loop) or UseEffect (w/o for loop). I would expect that only the first loop matters in the ideal world.

Comment: @TaiweiTuan Yep, I know it is a contrived example. Initially, I have just investigated useEffect and useLayoutEffect difference. For this purpose, I check that that browser paints a new state before completion of useEffect. That’s why I added this computationally intensive loop.

Comment: I would be grateful if you can tell me how to achieve a long delay (first gif) when putting `for` loop inside `if` condition. So far, I have not been able to do it, even if I increase the loop to 1e10.

Comment: @Trarbish could you please check the latest edited answer and see if that helps?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Eventually, I changed my code to have just one execution of a for loop. Now, I have a better understanding of what's happening.

You can find the results of my 'study' here:

https://github.com/esinmy/useEffect-vs-useLayoutEffect

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use logs without `<StrictMode>` to understand this better:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

let nRender = -1;
let nEffect = -1;

function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);
  console.log(`Render@${++nRender} with \`value\`: ${value}`);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`Render@${nRender} -> Effect@${++nEffect}`);
    // console.log(`Render@${nRender} -> Effect@${nEffect} -> Delaying`);
    // for (let index = 0; index < 1e9; index++) {}
    if (value === 0) {
      console.log(
        `Render@${nRender} -> Effect@${nEffect} -> Delaying because \`value === 0\``
      );
      for (let index = 0; index < 1e9; index++) {}

      const newValue = Math.random();
      console.log(
        `Render@${nRender} -> Effect@${nEffect} -> Setting \`value = ${newValue}\``
      );
      setValue(newValue);
    }
  }, [value]);

  return (
    <div>
      value: {value}
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => (console.log("Click -> Setting `value = 0`"), setValue(0))}>
          UseEffect
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

#### Outside of the `if` statement:

```
Render@0 with `value`: 0 
Render@0 -> Effect@0 
Render@0 -> Effect@0 -> Delaying 
Render@0 -> Effect@0 -> Setting `value = 0.27900865861181834` 
Render@1 with `value`: 0.27900865861181834 
Render@1 -> Effect@1 
Render@1 -> Effect@1 -> Delaying 
Click -> Setting `value = 0` 
Render@2 with `value`: 0 
Render@2 -> Effect@2 
Render@2 -> Effect@2 -> Delaying 
Render@2 -> Effect@2 -> Setting `value = 0.3376377689722845` 
Render@3 with `value`: 0.3376377689722845 
Render@3 -> Effect@3 
Render@3 -> Effect@3 -> Delaying
```

#### Inside the `if` statement:

```
Render@0 with `value`: 0 
Render@0 -> Effect@0 
Render@0 -> Effect@0 -> Delaying because `value === 0` 
Render@0 -> Effect@0 -> Setting `value = 0.3299433141099477` 
Render@1 with `value`: 0.3299433141099477 
Render@1 -> Effect@1 
Click -> Setting `value = 0` 
Render@2 with `value`: 0 
Render@2 -> Effect@2 
Render@2 -> Effect@2 -> Delaying because `value === 0` 
Render@2 -> Effect@2 -> Setting `value = 0.28265359531064593` 
Render@3 with `value`: 0.28265359531064593 
Render@3 -> Effect@3
```

#### Observations

You have a total of four renders, and all of them are because `value` has changed. So with every render, the effect will run, which means without any checks, the `for` loop will also run.

Painting the UI will be blocked because a `for` loop is a synchronous operation, according to [MDN - Main thread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Main_thread):

> The main thread is where a browser processes user events and paints. By default, the browser uses a single thread to run all the JavaScript in your page, as well as to perform layout, reflows, and garbage collection. This means that long-running JavaScript functions can block the thread, leading to an unresponsive page and a bad user experience.
>
> Unless intentionally using a [web worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers), such as a [service worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers), JavaScript runs on the main thread, so it's easy for a script to cause delays in event processing or painting. The less work required of the main thread, the more that thread can respond to user events, paint, and generally be responsive to the user.

So if you intend to run heavy synchronous tasks. You may want to [use service worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers)

If you want to achieve a delay, you want to use [`setTimout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout), one approach could be [debouncing](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-debounce-example/):

```
import { useState } from "react";

function debounce(func, timeout = 500) {
  let timer;
  return (...args) => {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      func.apply(this, args);
    }, timeout);
  };
}

function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      value: {value}
      <div>
        <button onClick={debounce(() => setValue(Math.random()), 500)}>
          UseEffect
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you. Looks like picture titles are mixed up though.
So the difference is that `for` loop will be called twice in case it is outside the condition. But it is not obvious why the second loop causes delay in painting. I thought that `useEffect` should work async and does not affect to "visual" render.
How to achieve similar kind of delay with `for` loop inside `if` condition?

Comment: Yeah you are correct the pictures were mixed up, thanks!

Comment: As a general rule, since you have a single thread, any **sync** operation would block **everything** on the page except service workers, even if you wrap it in an async method/use it in an async context. If you have a heavy sync operation check out [using service workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers).

Comment: Please [don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1048572), there's no reason not to just put the logs in a blockquote! Also this answer would benefit from explicitly pointing out the difference between the two logs and why that affects the user experience.